# Why am I getting a 'Server Error' when trying to use ContactsApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to use AppsScript to get a list of mailing addresses from my Google contacts (it's Christmas card time), but I'm getting a server error right at the start.   To make it as simple as possible, this is the start of the code; it's taken exactly from the reference documents, only changing the group name (and I do have a group called 'Cards') :

```
function getAddresses(){
  var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Cards');
};
```

I've added a scope to appsscript.json as specified in the reference materials at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
    ]
}
```

When I try to run this from the editor, I get

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
getAddresses    @ Code.gs:2
```

I've waited a bit and tried again - a few times!  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The error you're getting isn't reproducible on my end when I've tested. It may possibly be a temporary error as per the [official Apps Script troubleshooting doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#server_not_available_or_server_error_occurred_please_try_again) guide. However, if this error consistently occurs on your end, you may want to do the last step, which is to report the issue to the [Google issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#bugs) as this could be a possible bug.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, @IrvinJayG.: I decided to start again from scratch as it occurred to me that the work I started on this last year might have fallen foul of some change.  Starting a new project and doing apparently the same thing worked - but I notice that the standard appsscript.json now contains a 'runtimeVersion' setting, which may be relevant?

Comment: I see, yes, it could be as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration) `If you have an existing script using the Rhino runtime and want to make use of V8 (the updated one) syntax and features, you must migrate the script to V8.`